# how to close ViewPagerIndicator after last tab

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I am using Jake Wharton's [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) to display a swippable wizard-like UI under which user swipes between tabs to learn more about how my application works. I need to close current activity/view when user swipes to the right on last swipable tab. How to do that?